# how to track time spent in creating a Task record in salesforce against a case

Tags: apex, activities

My requirement is to find out how much time is being spent by sales rep while working on cases . 
So I need to track how much time is being spent by sales rep in creating a task record against the case.

Could anyone tell me how to find how much time spent in creating a task record against the a particular case.

Thanks

Comment: In order to get a good answer, pls elaborate on your requirement. What do you mean by "how much time spent in creating a task record against the a particular case."? The time between Case creation and the creation of the first taks? Or the time between creation of a task and closing of the task?

Comment: @guy, I am sorry if I was not clear. I need to have a timer functionality on the Task Create/Edit page . On the standard Task Create/Edit page, user should be able to start/stop the timer and the time difference should be saved on some custom field. So that in future , user can track how much hours he spent in working on that task.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your question? If you did, please make sure to post your solution as the answer.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? None of the answers are accepted. I'm curious because I may need to achieve a similar goal in the future.

Comment: @ProgrammableMedley I really dont think there is any good solution to achieve this unless its a custom UI. Let me know if you found anything as I am looking to achieve a similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

After going over the issue rather thoroughly I believe I came up with a simple (**untested**) solution.

First thing, I needed was to create three custom `DateTime` fields on the Task object.

These fields were:

- `StartTime__c`
- `EndTime__c`
- `TimeElapsed__c`

Now that I have the custom fields to store the time differences properly.

The next step was to create a trigger and utility to implement the time tracking functionality.

First, the trigger code:

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task(before insert, before update)
{
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        DateTime startingTimeForTimer = System.Now();

        for(Task singleTask : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(TaskTimeTrackingHandler.NeedsToTrackTime(singleTask))
                singleTask.StartTime__c = startingTimeForTimer;
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        List<Task> tasksThatNeedTimeRecorded = new List<Task>();

        for(Task singleTask : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(TaskTimeTrackingHandler.NeedsToStoreTimeDifference(singleTask, Trigger.OldMap.get(singleTask.Id))
                tasksThatNeedTimeRecorded.add(singleTask);
            if(TaskTimeTrackingHandler.NeedsToRestartTimer(singleTask, Trigger.OldMap.get(singleTask.Id))
                singleTask.EndTime__c = null;
        }

        if(tasksThatNeedTimeRecorded.size() > 0)
            TaskTimeTrackingHandler.StoreTimeDifferences(tasksThatNeedTimeRecorded);
    }
}
```

The trigger code is straight-forward. I used some utility methods in my handler class (`TaskTimeTrackingHandler`) to handle logic in methods to not clutter up the trigger.

For an insert (a before insert), I will simply check to see if a Task has a Case against it. If it does have a Case against it, I start the timer by placing the System time in the `StartTime__c` custom field.

For updates, it is a bit trickier, although not too complex.

If the `EndTime__c` custom field is assigned a value, we will store it in a list to store the time differences in the `TimeElapsed__c` field. If the `StartTime__c` has changed, we will reset the timer by setting the `EndTime__c` to `null`.

Now let's look at the handler class to see the implementation of the handler methods a bit further:

```
public with sharing class TaskTimeTrackingHandler
{
    public static String CasePrefix = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();

    public static Boolean NeedsToTrackTime(Task newTask)
    {
        return newTask.WhatId != null && newTask.WhatId.startsWith(CasePrefix);
    }

    public static Boolean NeedsToStoreTimeDifference(Task newTask, Task oldTask)
    {
        return NeedsToTrackTime(newTask) &&
            newTask.EndTime__c != null &&
            oldTask.EndTime__c == null &&
            newTask.StartTime__c != null;
    }

    public static Boolean NeedsToRestartTimer(Task newTask, Task oldTask)
    {
        return newTask.StartTime__c != oldTask.StartTime__c && NeedsToTrackTime(newTask);
    }

    public static void StoreTimeDifferences(List<Task> tasksThatNeedToStoreTimeDifferences)
    {
        for(Task singleTask : tasksThatNeedToStoreTimeDifferences)
        {
            singleTask.TimeElapsed__c = 
                ((singleTask.TimeElapsed__c == null 
                 ? 0 : singleTask.TimeElapsed__c.getTime()) +
                (singleTask.EndTime__c.getTime() - singleTask.StartTime__c.getTime()));
        }
    }

    private static Boolean TaskHasCaseHours(Task singleTask)
    {
        return NeedsToTrackTime(singleTask) && singleTask.TimeElapsed__c != null;
    }

    public static Long GetHoursSpentOnCase(Task taskToFindHoursOnCase)
    {
        if(TaskHasCaseHours(taskToFindHoursOnCase))
            return taskToFindHoursOnCase.TimeElapsed__c.getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I placed all the logic to check the Task fields in my handler for a cleaner trigger like I said before. Plus, I was able to reuse some methods, like `NeedsToTrackTime`.

Everything else is pretty simple now that it is broken down.

I specifically made sure that if the `TimeElapsed__` field had a value, any time differences will be accumulated. This was if you consistently start and stop your timer, you will get an accumulative difference in a `DateTime` value.

Lastly, here is an example below on how to use the trigger to track time, with comments above each one to show what it's doing.

```
//To start the timer on a particular Task, simply create a Task against a Case object
INSERT taskWithCaseAgainstIt;

//To stop the timer and have the trigger record the time spent on it, simply assign a
//DateTime to the EndTime__c custom field
taskWithCaseAgainstIt.EndTime__c = System.Now();
UPDATE taskWithCaseAgainstIt;

//To restart the timer, assign a new start time (StartTime__c) to your Task with the 
//case against it and it will return the EndTime__c custom field to null.
taskWithCaseAgainstIt.StartTime__c = System.Now();
UPDATE taskWithCaseAgainstIt;

//Now if you set an end time again, the time difference will be accumulated
taskWithCaseAgainstIt.EndTime__c = System.Now();
UPDATE taskWithCaseAgainstIt;

//Now to get the hours spent on a given case, you can use the static method GetHoursSpentOnCase
Long hoursSpentOnCase = TaskTimeTrackingHandler.GetHoursSpentOnCase(taskWithCaseAgainstIt);
```

There is some room for improvement, such as clearing the `TimeElapsed__c` field should clear the `StartTime__c` and `EndTime__c` fields. Other than that, I believe this will give you the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing a simple trigger on task:

```
Trigger TaskAfter on Task(After insert){
    Set<Ids> caseIds = new Set<Ids>();

    for(Task t: tigger.new) {
        if(t.whatID !=null && String.valueOf(t.whatID).substring(0,3) =='500')
            caseIds.add(t.whatID);
    }

    List<case> csLst = [select id,First_Task_created_date__c from Case 
        where First_Task_created_date__c=null && ID IN :caseIds];

    for (Case c : csLst ){
        c.First_Task_created_date__c=System.NOW();
    }

    update csLst;
}
```

Note: First_Task_created_date__c is a custom field to capture first task created date.

Then you can create a new formula field to calculate the number of days between Case created date and First task created date.